# Why is optionsText in single quote? Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am going through Knockout training.(Tutorial by John Papa).I have two questions

1. Why is shortDescription in single quotes
2. How are we able to access 'shortDescription' within the context of
   'lines'.shortDescription is a property in  my.Product ,but then how
   are we able to access it directly? Shouldn't be it like 
   'my.Product.shortDescription'

JavaScript:

```
my.Product=function(){      
    this.id=ko.observable();
    this.salePrice=ko.observable();
    this.photo=ko.observable();
    this.shortDescription=ko.observable();
    this.photoUrl=ko.computed(function(){
        return photoPath+this.photo;
    });
};
my.LineItem=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.product=ko.observable();
    self.quantity=ko.observable(1);
    self.extendedPrice=ko.computed(function(){
        return self.product() ? self.product().salePrice() * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
    });
};
my.vm={
        products:ko.observableArray([]),
        lines:ko.observableArray([new my.LineItem()])
};
```

HTML Code

```
<div data-bind="foreach:lines">
<select data-bind="options:$parent.products, value:product,optionsText:'shortDescription', optionsCaption:'Select a product ...'""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes and double quotes are the same to Javascript, but you use single in the data-bind because the HTML attribute requires double quotes.

The data binding can generally refer by name to any member of the model (which is what is passed to ko.applyBindings). In some contexts (within `foreach` and `with` bindings), you'll be referring to sub-members, and to refer to the model's members you have to preface the reference with $root.

Update: I'm sorry, I was careless reading the code. The 'shortDescription' is the name of the member to be used as optionsText, and it is relative to whatever is given as the options binding for the select (in this case, $parent.products).

Comment: I agree to what you said i.e "data binding can generally refer by name to any member of the model"  But shortdescirption is not there on my.vm .                                                                                             In this eg,binding happens                                      ko.applyBindings(my.vm); i.e on my.vm object and shortDescription is not part of that.

Comment: any more answers please?

Comment: Note that I updated my answer. Is it clear how shortDescription is being referenced?

Comment: Thanks for your update.So what i understand from you is that when i used "foreach:lines" context(this) changes to every line item in the lines observableArray.However, when i am using <select>, context changes again (for that particular select element)based on the object we use to populate its contents. Hope this understanding is correct.

Comment: In particular, the optionsText and optionsValue are evaluated as if the options binding provided a with context for each of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "Why is shortDescription in single quotes"...

shortDescription is in single quotes because the current scope is a `LineItem`, not a `Product`. Knockout takes unadorned values like `product` and looks them up on the current scope to get a value. If it sees `shortDescription`, it will look for `this.shortDescription` **on the `LineItem`**, not on the `Product`. It will proceed to use this value (`null`) as a property lookup on the `Product`.

Knockout does a property lookup for `optionsText` because the normal `theProduct.shortDescription` syntax would require you first to bind a variable (e.g. `theProduct`) to each of the `products`. Really, what you're doing is providing a function for extracting an `optionsText` from each of the `options`, and Knockout provides a shortcut if you want to just give a property name. In fact, you're free to provide a function instead, as in [Example 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).